# In Sencha Touch 2, how do you make the Scroll Idicators show permanently?

Tags: extjs, touch, sencha-touch-2

I have been through the Sencha forums and found that other people have asked this question and it was answered. However, I cannot seem to reproduce any solutions. I've tried:

```
Ext.override(Ext.scroll.indicator.CssTransform, {hide: function() {return false;},initialize:function(){this.show();}});
Ext.override(Ext.scroll.indicator.Default, {hide: function() {return false;},initialize:function(){this.show();}});
Ext.override(Ext.scroll.indicator.ScrollPosition, {hide: function() {return false;},initialize:function(){this.show();}});
```

and tried:

```
Ext.override(Ext.util.Scroller.Indicator, {
    hide: function() {
        var me = this;
        if (this.hideTimer) {
            clearTimeout(this.hideTimer);
        }
        return this;
    }
});
```

These links below are what I'm trying to reproduce. Has anybody had any luck making the scroll bars always show in Sencha Touch 2? And where would one enter the CSS trick in Sencha Architect (discussed in the websites bellow)?

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?146621-Making-List-Scroll-Idicators-show-permanently

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?151468-Making-scrollbar-visible-all-the-time

Comment: Ext.override is deprecated in ST2. You need to use Ext.define with the override config instead. See http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext-method-override It might help

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your apps css file:

```
.x-scroll-indicator {
    opacity: 0.5 !important;
}
```

this should always make it visible

Comment: I am using Sencha Architect and creating a simple form panel. I added a local CSS file and pasted the text you recommended and it didn't work. The scroll bar still disappears. I know the CSS file is being referenced by the app.html and Sencha Architect verifies the file exists and in the right place. Do I have to enable some scroll option somewhere? I already turned on vertical scroll...

Comment: Can you verify using web inspector toolbar that this style is indeed applied on the scroll indicator? If using Chrome right clock on scroll bar and select "inspect Element".

Comment: Perhaps the CSS file isn't being applied correctly? My url value is: './resource/css1'   Should I not use relative paths in my app.html file? (i.e. <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resource/css1">)

Comment: After I clicked on Inspect Element, it provided me with: <div class="x-scroll-bar active x-scroll-bar-y" id="ext-element-119"><div class="x-unsized x-scroll-indicator-dark x-scroll-indicator rounded x-scroll-indicator-y" id="ext-component-2" style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -10000px, 0px); "><div id="ext-element-123"></div><div id="ext-element-125" style="top: 3px !important; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scaleY(57); "></div><div id="ext-element-124" style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 60px, 0px); "></div></div></div>

Comment: What do you as CSS if you select div which has class "x-scroll-indicator"? You should not add your CSS in app.html, it should be added to app.json

Comment: Thanks for your continued help with this. I am using Sencha Architect and the app.json file doesn't exist. I had to use the package command from Sencha Architect to create the app.json file and index.html. The app.json file only applies to the index.html file. The problem now is that I think Sencha Architect has a bug since the index.html file doesn't include a script line that references "sencha-touch-all.js". Without that line, only the app.html file works. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: I haven't used Architect... sorry can't help